# Important lemma to prove that $|f^{-1}(y)|$ does not depend on $y \in Y$ when $f$ : $X → Y$ is local homeo between cpt connected Hdf spaces.

Tags: general-topology

Let us assume $X$ and $Y$ are compact connected Hausdorff topological spaces. If $f$: $X$ → $Y$ is local homeomorphism, how it can be proven that $φ$: $Y$ → $\mathbb{N}$; $y \mapsto |f^{-1}(y)|$ is a local constant function?

You can easily see that $φ(y)$ = $|f^{-1}(y)|$ is always finite under the conditions I described above. If the lemma is proven, it seems that $|f^{-1}(y)|$ does not depend on $y$. In other words, it will be proven that $φ$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that $f$ is onto: $f$ is open, being a local homeomorphism, so $f[X]$ is closed (compact) and open and non-empty in the connected space $Y$ so must equal $Y$.

If $y$ is any point in $Y$, $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is closed (hence compact) in $X$ and so cannot be infinite: if it were, it would have an accumulation point $p$, and at that point we would violate the local homeomorphism condition (infinitely many points $p$ in any neighbourhood of $p$ would map to $y$, violating local 1-1 ness).

So let $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ be those points of $X$ that map to $y$, the finite fibre. For each $x_i$ we have a neighbourhood $U_i$ such that $f\restriction_{U_i}: U_i \to f[U_i]$ is a homeomorphism; WLOG we can take the $U_i$ to be pairwise disjoint (as $X$ is Hausdorff). But then define $W(y)= \bigcap_{i=1}^n f[U_i] \cap (Y\setminus (f[X\setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i])$ which is an open neighbourhood of $y$ such that every point in $W(y)$ has exactly $n$ preimages (one in each $U_i$). So $y \to |f^{-1}[\{y\}]|$ is locally constant, hence constant by connectedness again, so we're done.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to show that $g(y)=|f^{-1}(y)|$ is continuous. You have remarked that $g(y)$ is finite. Let $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ since $f$ is local homeomorphism, there exist open subsets $U_1,...,U_n$, $x_i\in U_i$, an open subset $V$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $U_i$ is an homeomorphism onto $V$.

Firstly we remark that there exists an open subset $W\subset V$ such that $f^{-1}(W)\subset U_1\cup..\cup U_n$, if it is not true since $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, there exists a sequence $(y_i), limx_i=y$ and $f^{-1}(y_i)$ is not contained in $U_1\cup..\cup U_n$, to see this suppose that $f^{-1}(V)$ is not contained in $U_1\cup...\cup U_n$ and $y_1$ such that $f^{-1}(y_1)$ is not contained in $U_1\cup..\cup U_n$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist a non empty open subset $V_1\subset V$ such that $y_1$ is not in $V_1$, we replace $V$ by $V_1$ and construct $y_i$ recursively.

we denote $z_i\in f^{-1}(y_i)$ and $z_i$ is not in $U_1\cup..\cup U_n$. Since $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, there exists a subsequence $z_{i_q}$ which converges towards $z$, $f(z)=limf(z_{i_q})=y$, implies that $z=x_{i_0}$, we deduce that there exists $Q$ such that $q>Q$ implies that $z_{i_q}\in U_{i_0}$, contradiction.

We deduce that the restriction of $g$ to $W$ is constant and $g$ is continuous.

Comment: The existence of $W$ is a standard consequence of $f$ being a closed map: $f: X \to Y$ is closed iff for every $y \in Y$ and every open $U$ in $X$ such that $f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subseteq U$ we have an open $V$ in $Y$ such that $y \in V$ and $f^{-1}[V] \subseteq U$. A useful and ubiquitous lemma.

Answer (score 0):

We try to show that $\phi:Y\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a locally constant function, then if we do so, it will follow that $\phi$ is constant because $Y$ is connected ($\phi(Y)$ must lie in a connected component of $\mathbb{N}$, which has dicrete topology).
Now from hypotesis on $f$, we can find $\{U_{i}\}_{i}$ with $U_{i}\subseteq X$ open and $\{V_{i}\}_{i}$ with $V_{i}\subseteq Y$ open such that $X=\cup U_{i} $ and $f:U_{i}\rightarrow V_{i}$ is a homeomorphism. Now from hypothesis of compactness we can assume that these collection are finite, say with index $i=1,...,n$. Now take $y_{0}\in Y$, suppose $y_{0}\in f(X)$, so we take all of $V_i$'s which contain $y_0$, we can say that these are $V_{1},...,V_{r}$, in other words $y_0\in V_{1}\cap...\cap V_{r}$ and $|f^{-1}(y_0)|=k\leq r$ because $f:U_{i}\rightarrow V_{i}$ is a homeomorphism. Now say $f^{-1}(y_0)=\{x_{1},...,x_{k}\}$, because $X$ is Hausdorff we can find some pairwise disjoint open sets $W_{1},...,W_{k}$ with $x_{i}\in W_{i}\subseteq V_{i}$. We see that if $y\in f(W_{1})\cap...\cap f(W_{k})$ then $|f^{-1}(y)|=k$.
So $\phi$ is constant on the $y_0$'s open neighborhood $V=f(W_{1})\cap...\cap  f(W_{k})$. If $y_{0}\notin f(X)$, because $f(X)$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff you can find a neighborhood $N$ of $y_{0}$ disjoint from $f(X)$, then conclude $|f^{-1}(y)|=0$ on $N$.